# How to provide Coredump support in ARM Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

We have appilication running on top of ARM processor and layer of Linux arm in between ,We have requirement to provide Coredump support when a process at application crahes,We have idea like to provide ulimit unlimited option somewhere but not sure where in kernel

We have Yocto as our build environment .

Would like to know how and where we can provide this Coredump support .

Comment: 1: there is nothing ARM-specific about this.
2: while somewhat programming-related, this is more of a basic Linux/Unix usage question - so I would suggest moving it to one of the superuser or unix sites.

Answer (score 1):

Start with reading [core manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/core), you are probably just looking for `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`.

[If your shell does not have `ulimit` support](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit), you may need to call [setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit).